# JVM flag -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions, is this removed from the latest JDK8 (Update 265)?

Tags: java-8, jvm

I tried this but got no result -

```
$ java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
openjdk version "1.8.0_265"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_265-8u265-b01-0ubuntu2~20.04-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.265-b01, mixed mode)
```

Is the flag `UnlockExperimentalVMOptions` removed or
Am I doing something wrong or what??

Answer (score 2):

`UnlockExperimentalVMOptions` is itself an experimental VM option :)

To see it in the list of flags, use `-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions`

```
java -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
     bool UnlockExperimentalVMOptions        := true        {experimental}
openjdk version "1.8.0_265"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_265-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.265-b01, mixed mode)
```

BTW, there is a great project by Chris Newland - [VM Options Explorer](https://chriswhocodes.com/vm-options-explorer.html)